# Plotting heatmaps in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

So, here I am trying to plot heatmaps in gnuplot. I have a matrix-formatted text file (with row and column headers), and the command I am using to plot it is

```
plot "file.txt" matrix rowheaders columnheaders using 1:2:3 w image notitle
```

The output is this graph: [image]

Obviously, the X and Y labels are useless like this. I believe the problem here is that gnuplot is extracting all labels from the file and plotting them. How would I go about reducing the amount of clutter in here, e.g. plotting every 10th label or so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot reduce the number of labels plotted with `rowheaders columnnheaders`. Do you really need them? Looks to me like you can use normal numerical labels.

Comment: Well, no, I don't really require them to be there. Oh well, I'll just remove them completely. Thanks for clearing things up for me.

Comment: On a somewhat (un)related note, is it possible to change the color coding scale to something more logarithmic?

Comment: Use `set logscale cb`.

Answer (score 1):

Or just make the picture resolution bigger... for instance like 1920,1080 or bigger... like this:

`set term pngcairo size 1920,1080`

or make the tics numbers like 1000000 smaller and make a label to show that the numbers written on the tics are 1000000 bigger... or both:)

Sorry for my english...